# PHP - regular expression to validate a username with 1 uppercase, any number of lowercase and at least 1 number?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My code is:

```
$user_patt = "/^[A-Za-z0-9]{8,20}$/";
```

however when I use the `preg_match` to validate the format:

```
if (preg_match("/user/i", $field)) {
    if (!preg_match($user_patt, $value)) {
        $error_array[] = "$value is an invalid $field";
   }
}
```

Then I keep getting an error for registering a name such as *Granted42*. Did I miss something?

Comment: why such limits on a username?

Comment: Its for a school project, that is really the only reason

Comment: A regex does not seem like the best choice (unless the order is upper-lower-numbers). Is it mandatory to use one?

Comment: It is mandatory to use 1 Uppercase at least 1 lower and at least 1 number

Comment: What I meant was, is it mandatory to use a regular expression?

Comment: ah yes for this assignment it is

Answer (score 0):

How about using 3 regular expressions?

```
if (!(preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]{8,20}$/', $value) &&  
      preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $value) &&
      preg_match('/[0-9]/', $value))) 
{
    $error_array[] = "$value is an invalid $field";
}
```

If you must use only 1 regular expression, you can try:

```
if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*|[A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*/', $value)) {
    $error_array[] = "$value is an invalid $field";
}
```

This simply states either an upper case letter appears before a number, or the other way around, but it no longer captures the 8 to 20 characters requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any other character than letter and digit:

```
$user_patt = '/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20}$/';
if (!preg_match($user_patt, $value)) {
    $error_array[] = "$value is an invalid $field";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you. I have updated it to look for 8 to 20 characters and require at least one upper, lower and digit. It will also not allow non-alphanumeric characters including white space.

```
$user_patt = '/^((?!.*[^a-zA-Z\d])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{8,20})$/';

if (!preg_match($user_patt, $value)) {
    $error_array[] = "$value is an invalid $field";
}
```

Comment: I understand half of that expression, I am still very new at this what does the asterisk and the ?= mean?

Comment: Still working on why it isn't work for you. Your regex is only validating whether or not the user entered something in that has either uppercase, lowercase or numbers. It doesn't check if it has one of each. My regex does check to make sure at least one of them is present.

Comment: `?= ` looks ahead trying to match `.*` any number of characters between 0 and unlimited, not including a new line. So do we have at least one capital letter? Do we have at least one lowercase letter? Do we have at least one digit? Are they within 8 to 20 character spaces? If so, we have a match.

Comment: You need to anchor the regex otherwise something like `$value = 'gRa90fkgkgjgjghjhkhkhkhlgkfkfkdjfkghlhkkfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfsafs';` is valid. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfcd9a9ed3f141f2f833e97675080a16866f7f68